# Xamarin Forms CurrentFocus in Android Acitivty is null

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, keyboard, focus

i am developing a new android solution which will be replacing the old windows ce solution. Back in the old app the user was able to navigate through menu via keyboard. For whatever reason that must be possible in the android app as well. The issue is that i do not have any kind input control on the main page (menu page). I found a workaround:

```
            var currentFocus = this.CurrentFocus;
        //var token = focusedView == null ? null : focusedView.WindowToken;
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
        //inputMethodManager.ToggleSoftInputFromWindow(token, ShowSoftInputFlags.None, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        //view.RequestFocus();
        inputMethodManager.ShowSoftInput(currentFocus, 0);
```

The target android api is 10. It worked well but since I have added the nuget package Rg.Plugins.Popup the CurrentFocus is null. The result is that the keyboard won't be opened. The weird part is that when I open a sub modul from the menu page and return back to menu page the CurrentFocus property is not null anymore. I tried to use a dummy page which will be opened at start and return back to the main page but it did not work.
I also tried to set the focus of the main page in the appearing event of the main page but this did not work either.
Does anyone here know how i can force a page to be the "CurrentView"?

Comment: You mean that your project works fine before you add Rg.Plugins.Popup？

Comment: yes the currentView was not null.

Comment: According to your code, I don't see where do you use Rg.Plugins.Popup, so I can not reproduce your problem at mu side.

Comment: I used it on a different location where I needed popups. However the porblem started when I included the initialization code that is requred for rg.plugins.popup. Luckily I was able to talk away the customer requirements since it really does not make sense to navigate through menu with keyboard on android these days. That had this "feature" in their old ce app and wanted to keep it but since most android devices are quiet good and touch we agreed on removing that "feature".